# Shiny SelectInput to generate filepath for renderImage

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I have a series of ".jpg" files within my www folder of my script. I want to have renderImage to render the image with the filename that is named "dateplatform.jpg" based on the inputs (date, platform) of my UI. When I try the script below within my server.r file the app isn't displaying any image. Any thoughts?

ui   (partial)

```
       fluidRow(
                column(width=12,
                imageOutput("platformimage")
                      )
               )
```

server (partial)

```
    filename <- reactive ({
    paste(input$date, input$platform, sep="")
    })

    output$platformimage <- reactive({
    renderImage({
    list(src = filename(),
         width = 600,
         height = 600)

            },deleteFile = FALSE)
    })
```

Comment: `renderImage` doesn't need to be embedded within a `reactive`

Comment: @HubertL I added it as reactive because I am getting "Warning: Error in file.info: invalid filename argument" the default selection for date,platform doesn't contain an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filename` has to have at least the extension attached to it, and it's probably safer to `normalizePath` it:

```
filename <- reactive({
    normalizePath(file.path(paste0(input$date, input$platform, '.jpg')))
})
```

If this fail, it's probably because of the server can't find the file. Check the path created by `filename()`, and fix inside `file.path()`

Hope this helps.

Comment: @G Gamba, I am indeed still seeing an issue. If I manually add the src to the direct filepath, it is generating an image fine, it is in trying to have it paste the name of the input for date and platform that the renderImage is having an issue with.  I do have it as a renderImage  in the server and imageOutput in the UI. Is that correct?

Comment: try to put `output$path <- renderText({filename()})` in server.R and `textOutput('path')` in the UI. What is the result?
Also, take out that `reactive` from `renderImage`